# smtp js error in sending contact form from html and javascript

Tags: smtpjs

can I use smtp js without elastic gmail, I am not able to send with my personal email in pure html css and javascript

I want to send a form data from html and javascript using smtp js
so what I want is please let me know if still it is possible to send data from without elastic gmail with smtp js